# How do I create a FormValue(Json) using the FormArray . Unable to add values inside Formarray

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem generating the final form json when using FormArray. Below is my HTML code

```
<div class="card p-4">
    <form [formGroup]="meetingForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row" formGroupName="meetingType">
                    <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Meeting Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
                            formControlName="meetingTypeId">
                            <option selected>------select------</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let meet of meetingType" [ngValue]="meet.meetingTypeId">
                                {{meet.meetingTypeName}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="startDate" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Start Date & Time</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">

                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" formControlName="startDate"
                            id="startDate">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
               
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputParicepants" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Participents:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8 border" style="width:fixed; overflow:auto; max-height:250px; ">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Select</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                    

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr  *ngFor="let part of participent; ; let i=index">
                                   
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" [value]="part.userId" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)"> 
                                        </th>
                                        <td>{{part.username}}</td>
                                        
                                       
                                </tr>
                               
        
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-4 offset-md-4 ">
                <button (click)="saveMeeting()" type="button"
                    class="btn-sm btn-success btn-block">Save</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" (click)="resetForm()" class="btn-sm btn-danger btn-block">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
 </div>
 <pre>{{meetingForm.value | json}}</pre> 
 </div>
```

and below is my .ts file where I have declared the meetingForm as below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// import meeting service

export class MeetingComponent {

meetingForm!: FormGroup;
meetingingVenue!: FormGroup;
meetingType!: FormGroup;
participants!: FormArray;
//This value is coming from API 
meetingType: any = [];

  //This value is coming from API and looks like this
  participent: Array<any>  = [
 {"userId":1, "username":"user1"},
 {"userId":2 , "username":"user2"},
 {"userId":3 , "username":"user3"}
];
// userId!:FormGroup; 

 constructor(private router: Router, private meetingService: MeetingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {


this.meetingForm = new FormGroup({
    meetingType: this.meetingType = new FormGroup({
    meetingTypeId: new FormControl('')
  }),
  
  startDate: new FormControl(''),
  participants :  new FormArray([new FormGroup({
    userId: new FormControl('')
  }
  ),])
});

}

}
```

I want to generate the final Json before submitting the form as below.

```
meetingForm:{
    meetingType:{
        meetingTypeId : "1",
    },
    startDate: "23-03-2023",
    participants : [
        {
        userId = "1"
        },
        {
 userId = "2"
        }
        
    ]

}
```

The participants checkbox should be displayed. which is happening in this case. But only the selected participants(checked) should be present in the final Json as specified above. I am unable to do so . Please help me to get the final result .

Comment: Could you create stackblitz?

Comment: You need to make your self a little do more effort, it seem like you only copy and paste any kind of bad code and you want to some of one solve for you. Please put only the important code, the result spected and screenshot of yorr error messajes. We dont need read bootstrap css for example

Answer (score 0):

// Your models

```
class MeetingType {
  meetingTypeId: string;
  meetingTypeName: string;
}

class Participent {
  userId: number;
  username: string;
}
```

// Your class

```
export class MeetingComponent implements OnInit {
  meetingType: MeetingType[] = [
    {meetingTypeId: '1', meetingTypeName: '1'},
    {meetingTypeId: '2', meetingTypeName: '2'},
    {meetingTypeId: '3', meetingTypeName: '4'},
  ];

  meetingForm: FormGroup;
  values: object;

  get participants() {
    return this.meetingForm.get('participants');
  }

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.listenForm();
  }

  createForm() {

    const participants: Participent[] = [
      {userId: 1, username: 'user1'},
      {userId: 2, username: 'user2'},
      {userId: 3, username: 'user3'}
    ];

    this.meetingForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        meetingType: new FormControl({meetingTypeId: '1'}, Validators.required),
        startDate: new FormControl('23-03-2023', Validators.required),
        participants: this.formBuilder.array([])
      }
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < participants.length; ++i) {
      this.addProduct(participants[i]);
    }

  }

  listenForm(): void {
    this.meetingForm.valueChanges.pipe()
      .subscribe(
        value => console.log(value),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('complete...')
      );

    this.meetingForm.controls.participants.valueChanges.pipe(
      map(value => value) // here you can build your obj
    )
      .subscribe(change => {
        console.log(change); // the final result
      });
  }

  addProduct(participent: Participent) {
    (this.participants as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        userId: new FormControl(participent.userId, Validators.required),
        username: new FormControl(participent.username, Validators.required)
      })
    );
  }


}
```

// Your html view

```
<form [formGroup]="meetingForm">

  <!--meetingType-->
  <select formControlName="meetingType">

    <option
      *ngFor="let meet of meetingType"
      [value]="meet"
    >
      {{meet.meetingTypeName}}
    </option>

  </select>

  <!--startDate-->
  <input
    type="datetime-local"
    formControlName="startDate"
    id="startDate">

  <!--participants"-->
  <table formArrayName="participants">
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let part of meetingForm.get('participants')['controls']; let i = index">
      <span [formGroupName]="i">
      <th>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          [value]="part"
          [formControlName]="'userId'"
        >
        </th>
        <td>{{part.username}}</td>
      </span>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```